# Unable to generate local notification in Swift (UIKIT)

Tags: swift, uikit

[image]

I am trying a test Local UserNotification by clicking on a button but it is not working when the app is open it is only fired when it is in background why is that so?

Answer (score 0):

```
UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self
```

Assign delegate with UNUserNotificationCenter and add below method.

```
func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, willPresent notification: UNNotification, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) {
   completionHandler (.banner)
}
```

This UNNotificationPresentationOptions "banner" show notification while app in foreground.